# navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage is null but only on first page load

Tags: javascript, service-worker

On the very first page load (after emptying IndexDB, cache and unregistering the service worker) or on the reload without cache (Ctrl + F5), I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null
```

And this error keeps coming for every other post message to the service worker. Until I reload the page another time (with cache). It's no race condition. Just something goes wrong when the page is loaded for the first time.

I just don't understand what. Any hints? Google didn't come up with anything.

The code that causes it, is the following:

```
const loadUUID = (callback, storename, data) => {
    let request = window.indexedDB.open(DBN, DBN_VERSION), db, tx, store, index;

    request.onerror = e => {
        console.log('request.onerror');
        console.log(e);
    };

    request.onsuccess = e => {
        db = request.result;
        tx = db.transaction('uuid', 'readonly');
        store = tx.objectStore('uuid');
        let cursor = store.openCursor(null, 'next');
        var mostRecent = null;

        cursor.onsuccess = e => {
            if (e.target.result) {
                mostRecent = e.target.result.value.uuid;
            }
        };


        tx.oncomplete = e => {
            db.close();
            if (data) {
                data.uuid = mostRecent;
                //navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(data);
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(serviceworkerRegistration => {
                    console.log('within ready');
                    return serviceworkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription();

                })
                .then(subscription => {
                    if (!subscription) {
                        console.log('subscription MISSING');
                    }
                    console.log('within then of subscription');
                    navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage(data); //line triggering the error

                });
            } else {
                callback(mostRecent);
            }
        };
    };
    request.onupgradeneeded = e => {
        let db = request.result;
        STORES.forEach(storename => {
            if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(storename)) {
                db.createObjectStore(storename, {autoIncrement: true});
            }
        });
    };
};
```

The commented out line causes the exact same issue. I thought it might be a race condition and another post on SO suggested to wait for the SW to be ready. But that didn't help in my case.

Comment: [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/controller), the "property returns `null` if the request is a force refresh (Shift + refresh) or if there is no active worker." So somewhere in the code the service worker is becoming inactive.

Comment: According to developer tools →application tab →Service Workers (in Chrome), the service worker is activated and is running. I just verified that and triggered some postMessage calls by clicking around in the web page, and the error keeps coming.

And: This happens within navigator.serviceWorker.read. If there was any problem with the service worker, the code should clash somewhere before, but not after this most defensively coded block.

Comment: I mean, the force reload behaves as documented in the MDN. But why? This leaves a web app dysfunctional after a forced reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(worker => {
            worker.active.postMessage(loggingdata); 
        });
```